# Reporting Services access via Management Studio and a C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

How do you grant someone access to select Reporting Services from the drop down within Management Studio as per the below image.

[image]

Also, I have a colleague who has full admin access to this however when they run the below with the credentials set to DefaultCredentials we seem still be getting an error:

```
namespace ReportingServicesJobsUtility
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListJobSSRS();
        }

        public static void ListJobSSRS()
        {
            //create instance of ReportingService2010 called server
            server.ReportingService2010 rs = new server.ReportingService2010();

            //user credentials running application to be used
            rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("","");

            //create array of jobs
            Job[] jobs = null;

            try
            {
                jobs = rs.ListJobs();
                ListRunningJobs(jobs);
            }

            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //make this a void?
        public static bool ListRunningJobs(server.Job[] jobs)
        {
            int runningJobCount = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Current Jobs");
            Console.WriteLine("================================" + Environment.NewLine);
            server.Job job = default(server.Job);
            foreach (var j in jobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("JobID: {0}", job.JobID);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Action: {0}", job.JobActionName);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", job.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Machine: {0}", job.Machine);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", job.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", job.Path);
                Console.WriteLine("StartDateTime: {0}", job.StartDateTime);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", job.JobStatusName);
                Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", job.JobTypeName);
                Console.WriteLine("User: {0}" + Environment.NewLine, job.User);
                runningJobCount += 1;
            }

            Console.Write("There are {0} running jobs. ", runningJobCount);
            //returning a true for no reason
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows and we believe this is down to credentials, unless anyone can also shed some light on this?

[image]

**edit**

If I use `rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"developmentserver\Administrator","password");` on our development server then this runs with no problems, so it seems that it does not like using DefualtCredentials, either that or mine and my collegue's AD credentials are not sufficient, so back to the original question how do we grant full access to our logons.

Comment: For the second part - why do you believe its down to credentials? Does the error occur straight away or after a period of time?

Comment: The error is happening on the try jobs = rs.listJobs() line, I believe that the rs.Credentials is the issue because this runs with no problems when we remove the DefaultCredentials line and use rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"devserver\Administrator","password"); instead....

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for advice on two very different issues and i have some idea for the second one only.
you are not describing the layout of the servers involved so i make the assumption that you are on a client machine accessing a webservice that is a bridge to reach a SSRS instance; webservice and SSRS are not on the same machine.
if this is the case then check if you are running into the [double hop issue](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the accounts you want in the Report Manager and setting the role assignment there?

Comment: yes, set to Admin there, still cannot log in via management studio or run my application using DefaultCredentials

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. I had to set the Role of each account who should access to "Content Manager". Then for each directory of Reports I had, I went to the folder settings -> Security -> Add Role Assignment, then added the account(s) again. After doing that I was able to access the reports through my application.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, these changes were made in the Report Server settings through the browser, not in Management Studio.